# How to build a matrix from a list pairing names with values

Tags: list, r, matrix

I have a list like the following:

```
> l <- list(a=c("a1","a2"), b=c("b1","b2"), c="c1")
> l
$a
[1] "a1" "a2"

$b
[1] "b1" "b2"

$c
[1] "c1"
```

I would like to convert it back to a matrix, so that each value is paired with the corresponding name. In this example the expected result is:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "a"  "a1"
[2,] "a"  "a2"
[3,] "b"  "b1"
[4,] "b"  "b2"
[5,] "c"  "c1"
```

What is the most efficient way to achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

Don't know about most efficient, but using your list:

```
l <- list(a=c("a1","a2"), b=c("b1","b2"), c="c1")
```

we can get the length of each component using `sapply()`

```
lens <- sapply(l, length)
```

the we just rep the names of `l` `lens` number of times and unlist `l` - here done in a single line:

```
cbind(rep(names(l), times = sapply(l, length)), unlist(l))
```

which gives the desired output:

```
R> cbind(rep(names(l), times = sapply(l, length)), unlist(l))
   [,1] [,2]
a1 "a"  "a1"
a2 "a"  "a2"
b1 "b"  "b1"
b2 "b"  "b2"
c  "c"  "c1"
```

Comment: Ha, it's a rare occasion when one can beat "fast and furious" @GavinSimpson to an answer! But then, you spent that extra time writing the nice commentary.

Comment: @Andrie - yep, I need to stop adding in all the accoutrements to my Answers if I am to beat you guys these days ;-)

Comment: It's not about the speed! I'll upvote answers with accoutrements over "cut and paste this" solutions everytime!

Answer (score 2):

```
cbind(rep(names(l), sapply(l, length)), unlist(l))

   [,1] [,2]
a1 "a"  "a1"
a2 "a"  "a2"
b1 "b"  "b1"
b2 "b"  "b2"
c  "c"  "c1"
```